# Nested Transactions - Delayed Durability

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, transactions

my understanding of nested transactions is that all transactions will only commit on the outermost commit - does this mean that if i have an inner commit with DELAYED DURABILITY = ON on an inner commit the DD will not work?

E.g :

```
   Begin Transaction
      ---code--
      Begin Transaction
       -- code --
      Commit With (Delayed_DUrability = On)
   Commit
```

Comment: [There are no nested transactions in SQL Server.](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)

Comment: Transactions are all-or-non regardless of delayed durability. All work is done in the outermost transaction and committed or rolled back via that single transaction.

Answer (score 2):

DELAYED DURABILITY = ON has nothing to do with nested transactions.
It used only to instruct SQL Server to turn off WAL protection for a transaction. 
DELAYED Durability firstly to be enabled and allowed on a database level to have any effect.

As the result, transaction duration can be faster, because SQL Server should not wait when data firstly written to a transaction log. But the price - is risk of data corruption if database crashed.

Next to this, SQL Server does not support autonomous transactions, so nested transactions is a kind of syntax sugar..:

[A SQL Server DBA myth a day: (26/30) nested transactions are real](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-2630-nested-transactions-are-real/)